# Items in my userbar are moving when the window is resized (CSS)

Tags: html, css

So, I am working on the userbar for this site -- http://beta.btcbidder.com

the problem I am having is this- I finally, FINALLY got all the *li* type items lined up where they should be on my screen using CSS.

That being said, I am having some re-size issues. When I scale the window smaller, my searchbox and signup/login items move to a new row below the userbar, and I don't really know how to fix that.

Ideas?

My current CSS Schema:

```
menu#userbar > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

menu#userbar > li a {
    border: 0px none transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 8px 4px;
}
menu#userbar > li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

menu#userbar > li:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
menu#userbar > li:first-child a {
    background-image: url('/media/images/logo.png');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 73px;
    height: 40px;
}
menu#userbar > li:nth-last-child(3) {
    padding-left: 500px;
}
menu#userbar > li > *:first-child {
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 4px;
}

menu#userbar > li > menu {
    background-color: #ADADAD; /* fallback */
    background-color: rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.9);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 32px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
menu#userbar > li:hover > menu {
    display: block;
}
menu#userbar > li > menu li {
    min-width: 160px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: while your code needs some work, the most important part is to define what do you want to happen once the window is resized. You must realize that once you resize the window, elements won't fit at some point, that's when you need to define "if window >800px do something"

Comment: u can use float right instead of margin left 500px

Answer (score 0):

**1** - Set `padding-right: 150px;` (change as you want) instead of `padding-left: 500px;` to `menu#userbar > li:nth-last-child(3)`

**CSS:**

```
menu#userbar > li:nth-last-child(3) {
    padding-right: 150px; /* change as you want */
}
```

**2** - Change the order of **Login** and **Signup** `<li>` tags and use `float: right;`

**HTML:**

```
<!--THIS ENDS THE SEARCH BAR       -->
<!----------------------------------->

<li class="right" style="float: right;">
    <a href="http://beta.btcbidder.com/login/">Login</a>
</li>
<li style="float: right;">
    <a href="">Signup</a>
</li>
```

### [EDITED]

I've checked your website and now you need to change your CSS `menu#userbar > li:last-of-type` to `menu#userbar > li:nth-child(5)`

**Use This:**

```
menu#userbar > li:nth-child(5) {
    padding-right: 120px; /* change as you want */
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
menu#userbar > li:last-of-type { /* change this with the above CSS */
    padding-right: 192px;
}
```

Comment: I made these changes, but I am still having the problem described above. Something to do with the size of my search box or something?

Comment: @user3175451 I've updated my answer now and let me know if it doesn't work :)